# Make columns from row names and arrange data accordingly (new data.frame(s))

Tags: r

I have my original data.frame looking like this:

```
df1
      Group Variable      Text
        AB        a   Sentence1
        AB        b   Sentence2
        AB        c   Sentence3
        XY        d   Sentence4
        XY        e   Sentence5
        XY        f   Sentence6
        ZW        g   Sentence7
        ZW        h   Sentence8
        ZW        i   Sentence9
```

Now I need to re-arrange it like this:

```
df2

     AB XY ZW     Text1     Text2     Text3
      a  d  g Sentence1 Sentence4 Sentence7
      b  e  h Sentence2 Sentence5 Sentence8
      c  f  i Sentence3 Sentence6 Sentence9
```

P.S: The reason my output data.frame looks like this, is that I would later concatenate Text1-Text3 columns per row. But I do it outside of R

**Great thanks for any help!**

Code for df1 & df2:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Group = c("AB", "AB", "AB", "XY", "XY", "XY", "ZW", "ZW", "ZW"), 
                  Variable = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"), 
                  Text = c("Sentence1", "Sentence2", "Sentence3", "Sentence4", "Sentence5", "Sentence6", "Sentence7", "Sentence8", "Sentence9"))

df2 <- data.frame(AB = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                  XY = c("d", "e", "f"), 
                  ZW = c("g", "h", "i"), 
                  Text1 = c("Sentence1", "Sentence2", "Sentence3"), 
                  Text2 = c("Sentence4", "Sentence5", "Sentence6"), 
                  Text3 = c("Sentence7", "Sentence8", "Sentence9"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `dcast` from `data.table` by specifying 'Variable' and 'Text' in the `value.var`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), rowid(Group) ~ Group, value.var = c('Variable', 'Text'))[, Group := NULL][]
```